# Vue js when clicked get the value of radio button

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, radio-button, vue-component

I am trying to created a filter component, but first I would like to be able to console.log() the value of the filter model base on the selected radio button.

```
<template>
  <Section>
    <h5>Filter</h5>
    <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
      <label class="btn btn-primary active">
        <input type="radio" name="filter" id="all" v-model="filter" value="all" />All
      </label>
      <label class="btn btn-primary">
        <input type="radio" name="filter" id="completed" v-model="filter" value="completed" />Completed
      </label>
      <label class="btn btn-primary">
        <input type="radio" name="filter" id="notcompleted" v-model="filter" value="notcompleted" />Not Completed
      </label>
      <button class="btn btn-primary" @click="consoleFilter">console the value</button>
    </div>
  </Section>
</template>
```

if the radio "all" is check, and I click the button the console_log value I want must also be "all"

```
<script>
export default {
  name: "Filter",
  data() {
    return { filter: null };
  },
  methods: {
    consoleFilter() {
      console.log(this.filter);
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

anyone know how I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

Well, so far I get the point that you are trying to get the value of checked button when it's clicked. Simply you can add `onChange` event to input tag as follows

```js
 <Section>
    <h5>Filter</h5>
    <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
      <label class="btn btn-primary active">
        <input type="radio" name="filter" @change="consoleFilter" id="all" v-model="filter" value="all" />All
      </label>
      <label class="btn btn-primary">
        <input type="radio" name="filter" @change="consoleFilter" id="completed" v-model="filter" value="completed" />Completed
      </label>
      <label class="btn btn-primary">
        <input type="radio" name="filter" @change="consoleFilter" id="notcompleted" v-model="filter" value="notcompleted" />Not Completed
      </label>
      <button class="btn btn-primary" @click="consoleFilter">console the value</button>
    </div>
  </Section>
```

and if you don't want to do this you can add a watcher too as

```js
watch:{
      filter(value){
        console.log(value)
      }
    }
```